# How to do makefile to compile multiple .cpp files in different directories using a single makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following files in my proj2 directories and need to compile them together to have one executable file.

```
    proj2/main.cpp
    proj2/model/Player.cpp
    proj2/model/gameBoard.cpp
    proj2/controller/TTTController.cpp
    proj2/Makefile
```

I'm using the following command inside my makefile, but it is not working.

```
all:
    g++ /project2_p1/main.cpp /project2_p1/controller/TTTController.cpp          /model/gameBoard.cpp /model/Player.cpp -o ttt
clean:
    -rm ttt
```

Can anybody help me please.Thank you

Comment: You need to read a basic Unix command-line terminal tutorial. What do you think a leading `/` means in a path?

Comment: You can't build something with Make until you know how to build it *without* Make.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you start learning `make` as it is one of the fundamental tools that programmers use. And, if you can learn `C++`, you can definitely learn `make`.

In your project you have source files buried in their own subdirectories so in order to find them all you can use the `$(shell find...)` command. Same with any header files in your project.

By making `all:` the *direct* target it gets executed unconditionally and you lose the benefits of using `make` - only compile when you change something.

Having said that the basic template I am providing here could be improved to recompile only those source files that have changed but that's an exercise for the reader.

I think this should work in your case:

```
# set non-optional compiler flags here
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors

# set non-optional preprocessor flags here
# eg. project specific include directories
CPPFLAGS += 

# find cpp files in subdirectories
SOURCES := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')

# find headers
HEADERS := $(shell find . -name '*.h')

OUTPUT := ttt

# Everything depends on the output
all: $(OUTPUT)

# The output depends on sources and headers
$(OUTPUT): $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(OUTPUT) $(SOURCES)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OUTPUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

thats my `minGW` project's makefile codes:

```
hepsi: derle calistir
Nesneler :=  ./lib/Hata.o ./lib/Hatalar.o ./lib/Dugum.o ./lib/ListeGezici.o ./lib/BagilListe.o

    derle:
        g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/Hata.o -c ./src/Hata.cpp
        g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/Hatalar.o -c ./src/Hatalar.cpp
        g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/Dugum.o -c ./src/Dugum.cpp
        g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/ListeGezici.o -c ./src/ListeGezici.cpp
        g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/BagilListe.o -c ./src/BagilListe.cpp
        g++ -I ./include/ -o ./bin/test $(Nesneler) ./src/test.cpp

    calistir:
        ./bin/test
```

In your project I think this will work;

```
    all: compile run
Objects :=  ./lib/Player.o ./lib/gameBoard.o ./lib/TTTController.o 

compile:
    g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/Player.o -c ./model/Player.cpp
    g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/gameBoard.o -c ./model/gameBoard.cpp
    g++ -I ./include/ -o ./lib/TTTController.o -c .controller/TTTController.cpp
    g++ -I ./include/ -o ./bin/main $(Objects) ./main.cpp

run:
    ./bin/main
```

`lib` folder contains .o files. You can chance it if you want.
`include` folder refers your header `.h` or `.hpp` files. You can change every one of them according to your headers location.

`bin` folder contains your `.exe` file called `main.exe`. You can change or remove it like that

```
run: 
   ./main
```

I hope it'll work.

@Galik has right. if you want to learn `C++`, you should definitely learn `make`.